# Let $\gamma$ be a piece wise smooth closed curve .show that $∫z^mdz=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let  $\gamma$ be a piece wise smooth closed curve .show that $∫z^mdz=0$ where $m=0,1,2...$

since  $\gamma$ is closed curve and $z^m$  is analytic so by cauchy theorem

$∫z^mdz=0$ is i am right?

Answer (score 0):

The equality is only correct if $m\neq -1.$ In that case $F(z)=\frac{z^{m+1}}{m+1}$ has $f$ as its derivative. So then
\begin{equation}
\int_\gamma f(z) dz=\int_0^1F'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) dt=F(\gamma(1))-F(\gamma(0))=0,
\end{equation} where the last inequality holds because $\gamma$ is closed.